# Undefined variable: POST in Vacía en PHP y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

El error me lo marca en la línea 13, con el error "Notice: Undefined variable: POST in C:\wamp64\www\myProject\registro.php on line 13". Pero no me específicia el nombre de la variable.
Dichas líneas de código son estas con las que recojo la fecha usando datepicker...

```
  $lugar_nacimiento = $_POST['lugar_nacimiento'];
  $fecha_nacimiento = $POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
```

Muestro las líneas 12 y 13 acá arriba.

Este es el código del formulario:

```
  <div class='dates'>
  <label for="fecha_nacimiento">FECHA DE NACIMIENTO: </label><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd"  
  placeholder="FECHA DE NACIMIENTO" id="fecha_nacimiento" 
  name="fecha_nacimiento" required>
 </div>
```

Comment: es como dice el error no existe la variable $POST , ya que debería ser $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'] , saludos

Comment: Gracias,fue un error muy tonto de escritura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta un guion bajo, por eso te marca el error:

Deberias cambiar

> $fecha_nacimiento = $POST['fecha_nacimiento'];

por

> $fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];

Comment: Tienes razón, justamente me dí cuenta en este momento que un error tan tonto puede hechar a perder todo. GRACIAS¡